# D3 link pattern

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am try to get the pattern of the link present in the below image,

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YK9h6.png]

For creating a link path, i am using the below code but not able to get the correct pattern (Reference code - https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/1a96af738c89b88723eb63456beb6510)-

```
const path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
    C ${(s.y + d.y) / 3} ${s.x},
      ${(s.y * 1.25)} ${d.x},
      ${d.y} ${d.x}`

return path
```

Answer (score 0):

You must to use the css property stroke-dasharray.
[Reference](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-css/stroke-dasharray.html)